# XamlParseException initialising a static class

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a `XamlParseException` in some code which is trying to select all the text in a `TextBox`.

Xaml:

Common:SelectAllTextOnFocus.IsTextSelectedOnFocus="True" />

Code behind:

```
public static class SelectAllTextOnFocus
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextSelectedOnFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTextSelectedOnFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(SelectAllTextOnFocus), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsTextSelectedOnFocusChanged));

    public static bool GetIsTextSelectedOnFocus(TextBox item)
    {
        return (bool)item.GetValue(IsTextSelectedOnFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsTextSelectedOnFocus(TextBox item, bool value)
    {
        item.SetValue(IsTextSelectedOnFocusProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnIsTextSelectedOnFocusChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = depObj as TextBox;
        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            item.GotFocus += OnGotFocus;
        }
        else
        {
            item.GotFocus -= OnGotFocus;
        }
    }
```

I get a XmalParseException, with the message: The type initializer for 'Common.SelectAllTextOnFocus' threw an exception.

Any ideas what's causing this, or how to go about debugging it?

The inner exception is: 'IsTextSelectedOnFocus' property was already registered by 'SelectAllTextOnFocus'.

This is being registered on creation in a static class - so how can it be being registered twice?

Comment: What's the `InnerException.InnerException`?

Comment: I've added the inner exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've caught this in the debugger, look at the `InnerException`, which should show you the exception which cause the `TypeInitializationException`. That should give you a lot more of a hint of where to look.

I can only see one line which *could* be the problem though:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextSelectedOnFocusProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTextSelectedOnFocus",
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(SelectAllTextOnFocus), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsTextSelectedOnFocusChanged));
```

That's the only code which would execute in the type initializer.

I can't see what's wrong with it offhand, but then  I'm not very familiar with registering dependency properties.

Comment: This was the problem - there was a second class which had clearly been copy-and-pasted which was still trying to register to the original class type.

Comment: @Jackson: Excellent - glad you found it :)

Answer (score 1):

The type intitializer (also known as a static constructor) runs the initializers for your `static` fields.

In other words, the `IsTextSelectedOnFocusProperty` initializer is throwing an exception.